# Editing Bootstrap 4.3.1 CSS, nothing changes

Tags: bootstrap-4

I edit bootstrap.css in my RazorPages project (like background color), save those and nothing changes. I must be doing something wrong, but what is that?

Comment: Maybe you're editing a copy of `bootstrap.css` that isn't actually getting read when you apply the styles.

Comment: When i edited site.css it worked. Looks like I can't really edit original file.